# How to reduce an array using lodash

Tags: lodash

I have the following array:

```
arr = [
    [
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]
    ],
    [
        [7, 8],
        [9, 10],
        [11, 12]
    ],
    [
        [13, 14],
        [15, 16],
        [17, 18]
    ]
];
```

How can I reduce it the following using lodash:

```
[[9,12],[27,30],[45,48]]
```

I am a complete noob. I don't know what to do beyond this:

```
_.forEach(arr, function (n) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_.zip(n)));
});
```

Some hints please.

Answer (score 3):

Using a mix of lodash ([`_.unzip()`](https://lodash.com/docs#unzip) and [`_.sum()`](https://lodash.com/docs#sum)) and Array methods ([`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

```
var result = arr.map(function(a) {
  return _.unzip(a).map(_.sum);
});
```

Comment: @Amit lodash is awesome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your attempt, combination of `map`, `zipWith` & `add` with some `partialRight` help :-)

```
var zipAdd = _.partialRight(_.zipWith, _.add)
var result = _.map(arr, function(a) {
  return zipAdd.apply(null, a)
});
```

#### Working snippet

```js
var arr = [
  [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]
  ],
  [
    [7, 8],
    [9, 10],
    [11, 12]
  ],
  [
    [13, 14],
    [15, 16],
    [17, 18]
  ]
];

var zipAdd = _.partialRight(_.zipWith, _.add)
var result = _.map(arr, function(a) {
  return zipAdd.apply(null, a)
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Amit what exactly is partialRight doing?

Comment: [partialRight](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) wraps a functions with some parameters locked in as constants. for example, if there exists `function f(a, b, c, d)` then after `partialF = _.partialRight(f, 4);` this will be true: `partialF(1, 2, 3) == f(1, 2, 3, 4)`